# Modify DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH for Apache? Perl CGI script not working when connecting to MySQL

Tags: mysql, perl, apache, cgi, dbi

I have a Perl CGI script that works fine when I run it from the command line with `./roster_return.cgi StudentID=101095` but when I run it in MAMP `(http://localhost:8888/cgi-bin/roster_return.cgi?StudentID=101095)`, I get the following error in my apache log:

```
[Wed May 02 10:56:47 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't load '/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle' for module DBD::mysql: dlopen(/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle, 1): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
[Wed May 02 10:56:47 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   Referenced from: /Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle
[Wed May 02 10:56:47 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   Reason: image not found at /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 207.
[Wed May 02 10:56:47 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]  at (eval 11) line 3
[Wed May 02 10:56:47 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Compilation failed in require at (eval 11) line 3.
[Wed May 02 10:56:47 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where expected
[Wed May 02 10:56:47 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]  at /Users/jerickson/Desktop/helpfulscripts/cgi-bin/roster_return.cgi line 16
[Wed May 02 10:56:47 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: roster_return.cgi
```

I now remember that a few years ago I had to add this line to my .bash_profile:

`export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/mysql/lib/"`

in order to get the command line perl scripts to work. This would explain why the library is not loading from MAMP, since it is not using my .bash_profile paths. How would I add this location for the MAMP server's path??

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try [Apache's mod_env](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_env.html) in your VirtualHost config:

```
SetEnv DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH path/to/libs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the line to the `apachectl` script:

`export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/libs"`

It's usually in the **bin** directory of Apache. I needed to load *pdo_informix* for a project and that's the only place that got it working.